# Why is my setInterval function only being called once?

Tags: javascript, oop, data-structures, event-handling, dom-events

I have an object/function that starts out like

```
function Game ( board, numBlocks ) {

    // ...

    this.speedMap = { "fast": 100, "medium": 300, "slow": 600 };
    this.curSpeed; 
    this.mover; // the setInterval(...) function that causes the snake's movement
                // This is set when a game is instantiated with startNew(...)

   // ... 

   this.Snake = function ( game )
   {

       this.createNew = function ( )
       {           
       
        // ... 

       }

       this.move = function ( )
       {
           console.log("The move() function got called!"); // test
       }
   }

   // ...

    this.startNew = function ( spd ) {

        // ...

        this.snake = new this.Snake(this);
        this.snake.createNew();

        // ... 

        this.curSpeed = spd;
        this.mover = setInterval(this.snake.move(), this.speedMap[this.curSpeed]);
    }
```

(For simplicity I've commented out all the code that shouldn't be relevant for my question)

and for some reason the function I'm attaching to `setInterval` is only being called once when I instantiate a game with

```
SG = new Game(snakeBoard, 16);
SG.startNew("medium");
```

where it should be getting called every `300` milliseconds.

**Live example:** http://playclassicsnake.com/play

**Full Javascript:** https://github.com/jamkin/Snake/blob/master/SnakeGame/Scripts/game.js

Look at the JS console in the above example and see

> The move() function got called!

printed only once.

What am I missing here?

**BONUS QUESTION:**

What is the equivalent of making a static object/function in object-oriented Javascript? Specifically, the

```
this.speedMap = { "fast": 100, "medium": 300, "slow": 600 };
```

in my object is the same for every such object that is instantiated, so it should be `const static` or whatever the JS equivalent is.

Comment: for your bonus question:
Since the function `Game` is considered the class. I would create a static method or property with: `Game.speedMap = ...` after the `Game` function (you can assign properties to functions because functions are also objects in js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
this.snake.move()
```

With:

```
this.snake.move
```

So, you'll have:

```
this.mover = setInterval(this.snake.move, this.speedMap[this.curSpeed]);
```

The first parameter of [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) is a function. You shouldn't call it.
What your code is doing, is passing the response from `this.snake.move()` to the `setInterval`

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Just a side note: you won't be able to use the snake object's properties from within move when its called from the interval, because `this` will be `window` and not the snake. you should create a closure.